# Add a page URL to a domain

Tags: html, redirect, indexing, dns

I feel bad for asking this, but I can't find any answer on the web from my Googling. Basically I'm making my portfolio of graphic design and I'm making each page statically, as in with HTML documents. I've run into a domain problem.

I have the home page called `index.html` so the domain (`http://blieque.comli.com`) goes straight there, but when it comes to another page I'm stuck. I want to go to `domain.com/page`, not `domain.com/page.html`. I know that creating another directory/folder for each page and calling all of them `index.html` would work, but that seems like a messy approach and I can't imaging pages are normally made like that.

Are sites just not static anymore? All help appreciated. :)

Oh, and `comli.com` is a `000webhost.com` domain. I'll be getting my own soon, but I want to get everything perfect first.

-Blieque

Comment: can u change htaccess of your site??

Comment: What access to you have to the server configuration? You'll need at least *some* to do this, otherwise you're limited to what your host offers you. it may be better to switch to your final host so that you know what's possible

Comment: iNan, yes I can. I already have to make custom HTTP error pages so it definitely works.

Comment: @Gareth, I'ms already on my final host. It's free but it's a good service and I won't be getting much traffic. I have full access to change `.htaccess` and I don't think I have many constraints so I guess so. What else is there? Sorry for being n00bish.

Comment: @iNan *didn't @ you in my reply*

Comment: You can use htaccess ReWriterule to do so it would be easy to configure. If you are unable to do let me know i will help you :)

Comment: @iNan I have close to no experience with editing `.htaccess`. How shall I use this rule? In other words, yes please. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.htaccess ReWriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule public$ public.html
RewriteRule about$ about.html
```

and so on, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a new directory on the server for each page and throw the index.html into each directory. It wont be as messy as you may think, assuming you don't have too many pages ..

I can't think of any other approach ..

Comment: Ok, I'll see what happens. And just to confirm, you say "the" `index.html`. You do mean each page just with the same name, right?

Comment: Not a problem, let me know how it works out for you if you decide to to that .. *edit* why did I get a downvote? I thought I offered a practical solution ..

Comment: On what? I didn't do so intentionally. Sorry if it was me. :| Also, I found a solution using `.htaccess` and the `RewiteRule`, but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: No worries, glad you found a better solution :)